# Journey Builder error - INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

Upon activating a journey, this error shows up:

> Flow Creation failed. Unable to activate the Journey, the Sales Cloud
>   user may not have correct permissions. Activating a Journey requires
>   Author Apex permissions.INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found
>   in SessionHeader: Illegal Session

I checked the permissions and `Author Apex` is checked. What else could be causing the issue?

What is the `INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session` referring to?

[image]

Comment: I saw this same error turn up in Einstein Analytics today...not sure it helps but it is curious

Comment: Which user did you check permissions on? Yours on the integration user?

Comment: Integration - mine is not integrated, we only use the API user for everything